# I have published an iOS app but forgot to add iaps in "version page", how can I add them afterwards?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I have just released an iOS app, it went through review and it have IAPs in the "features" page in itunesconnect only. Forgot to add them in apps version page too before submitting.
Can I add them afterwards somehow? The IAP section seems to be hidden now in version page.

If i need to submit a New version, should I cancel the apps distribution now? As the Apple staff are having a Xmas holidays.

Thanks.

Comment: You don't add IAPs to the version; only under features.

Comment: I have IAPs under features and the app is in appstore but why the IAPs are not working and they say "ready to submit"?

Comment: If they say "ready to submit" then you haven't submitted them for review.

Comment: How can I submit them for reviewed? The submit button is grayed out.

Comment: If you didn't submit them before you submitted your first app version then you will need to submit them with a new version. Also make sure that they have all of the metadata they need.